# SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax or access violation: 1064 you have an error in your SQL syntax

Tags: php, sql, pdo

hi am trying to run a sql query but it gives this error, i have reservations column in stores table and a reservations table which has firstname,lastname or email:

```
"SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax or access violation: 1064 you have an error in your SQL syntax;

 'FROM 
  reservations R
  LEFT JOIN 
 'at line 11"
```

code:

```
  public function getReservationData($store = null, $limit = 10, $offset = 1)

  {
      $em = $this->getEntityManager();
      $offset = ($offset -1) * $limit;
      $query = "SELECT
                    R.FirstName as firstName,
                    R.LastName as lastName,
                    R.Email as email,
                FROM reservaions R
                LEFT JOIN 
                    stores S
                       ON s.id = R.store
                WHERE
                    s.id = :store
                AND
                     S.reservation = 1";

                 $stmt->$this->getEntityManager()->getConnection->prepare($query);
                 $stmt->$bindParam(':store', $store);
                 $stmt->execute();
                 $result[] = $stmt->fetch();

                 return $result;
  }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
R.Email as email,
```

remove the "," and that will solve your problem